# What is the remap to change ControlShiftQ to a single key?

Tags: autohotkey

I have AutoHotKey, but am not smart enough to get the correct syntax for the script.

I have tried space::controlshiftQ and controlshiftq::space.  Keeps telling me I have unrecognized action.  Cannot find this specific question in all of their help pages.

What do I need to put in the script to get the computer to recognize that when I push the space bar, I want it to recognize that as pushing control,shift,and the letter Q all at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Using modifier keys is detailed in the [Hotkeys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)  documentation [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols).

The symbol for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>is `^`. The symbol for <kbd>Shift</kbd> is `+`.

```
Space::^+Q
```

You'll also likely want to take a look at the [Context-Sensitive](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Context) section, as I would assume you want to retain the function of your <kbd>Space</kbd> key in most cases.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please mark this as the answer.